# How to list the resource name in AWS Config advanced query

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to create an advanced query to list all the non-compliant resources along with their name and reason why they are non-compliant. For the resource name, I tried "configuration.targetResourceName" but that just results in having an empty column. I am also not sure how to add the reason for being non-compliant in my query, was hoping someone could please assist. This little query will list all non-compliant resource types and their resource ID.

```
SELECT
  configuration.targetResourceId,
  configuration.targetResourceType,
  configuration.complianceType
WHERE
  configuration.complianceType = 'NON_COMPLIANT'
```

Answer (score 0):

add `resource_type` in the Select and where clause.
Refer https://github.com/awslabs/aws-config-resource-schema/tree/master/config/properties/resource-types